# iOS center button on rotations

Tags: ios, rotation

I have a UIView that is a subview of another UIView. Within this UIView I have a button that I always want to be centered. The problem I am running into is that, since the subview can change sizes upon rotations, the button gets off centered. Is there a way to get auto-centering?

Comment: Could you provide some more implementation details. Is this setup in a xib/storyboard or code? Are you using autolayout?

Comment: It's entirely done programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the button center as the uiview center like this:

```
[myButton.setCenter:mySubView.center];
```

and then set autoresizing mask:

```
[myButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You would also need to add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` to keep it centered vertically.

Comment: mySubView isn't positioned at (0,0). My understanding of mySubview.center is that it is with to the superview's coordinate system. I think I am running into a frame vs bounds issue. Is there a way to center on a subview?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on auto-layout and center your button. You turn on auto-layout by selecting your view controller and on the right check auto-layout. Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: @user1802143 This is the best way.